# How to efficiently generate random number from COM-POISSON distribution via mean parametrization in R?

Tags: r, random, poisson

I know that `mpcmp::dcomp()` generates random numbers from COM-Poisson distribution. However, they fail to generate such data if mean is large.

The following example doesn't compute, or takes too much time:

```
mpcmp::rcomp(1, mu = 500, nu = 1)
```

How can I generate a COM-Poisson data with large mean efficiently?

Comment: You should file an issue at: https://github.com/thomas-fung/mpcmp/issues

Comment: Thanks. I just did: https://github.com/thomas-fung/mpcmp/issues/6

Answer (score 0):

[This was fixed in the package version on Github](https://github.com/thomas-fung/mpcmp/issues/6)

So, it is necessary to install the package via Github and run the simulation:

```
devtools::install_github("thomas-fung/mpcmp")
mpcmp::rcomp(1, mu = 500, nu = 1)
```